# Why $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle Dx,x\rangle$ holds for a diagonalisable matrix $A = XDX^*$?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, positive-definite, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $A$ be selfadjoint with $spec(A) \subset (0, \infty) $.
> Show that $\langle Ax, x\rangle > 0$ for $x \ne 0 $

---

Since $A$ is selfadjoint there is a matrix $X$ and $D$ such that $A=XDX^*$.
So:
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle  = \langle XDX^*x, x\rangle = \langle Dx,x\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i^2$$

Since all eigenvalues are positive the term is greater than zero for $x \ne 0$ but how can we reduce $\langle XDX^*x,x\rangle$ to $\langle Dx,x\rangle$?
Can someone explain what is happening between these two terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a self adjoint matrix is diagonalizable in an **orthonormal** basis. We get the result as the inner product is kept between orthonormal basis

$$\langle Ax,x\rangle  = \langle XDX^*x, x\rangle=\langle XDy, Xy\rangle = \langle Dy,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2$$

where $y=X^*x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you do me a favor and form $\langle XDX*x,x \rangle $ into $ \langle Dx,x \rangle$. It would be a lot easier for me to understand.